# What is physical storage in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

In this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing) of GCP, I found this information:

> Active storage includes any table or table partition that has been modified in the last 90 days.

> Long-term storage includes any table or table partition that has not been modified for 90 consecutive days. The price of storage for that table automatically drops by approximately 50%. There is no difference in performance, durability, or availability between active and long-term storage.

I see in billing that there is an extra section physical storage, what is the difference between physical storage and long term storage/active storage?

Comment: It might be better for you to contact [GCP Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing#how_to_contact_support) as they could explain this better.

Answer (score 0):

Physical storage is the amount of data stored on disk after compression, including bytes used for time travel storage.

It is possible to change a dataset billing model to use physical storage (cf. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets-intro#dataset_storage_billing_models)

See also how to monitor physical storage using the TABLE_STORAGE view: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-table-storage#calculating_storage_billing